# Get an attribute from one array in Mail blade Template

Tags: laravel

I cannot access to the attribute "price" in my Mail class in Laravel. I´ve got an error

*Undefined index: price (View: C:\laragon\www\hr-english\resources\views\external__emails\registered-course.blade.php)*

I think the problem is the controller. I had to do a query to the database to check the price of the course, because in my **registered_courses** table I have a foreign key related to **courses** which return to me the title of the course and its price.

When I got from the query those data and send the variables to the blade, it appears the error shown at the top.

My controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    try {

        $data = $this->getData($request);
        $email = Auth::user()->email;
        $name = Auth::user(); 
        $msg = $data;
        $price = DB::table('courses')->select('price')->where('id', '=', $request['course_id'])->get();

        RegisteredCourse::create($data);
        Mail::to($email)->queue(new RegistCourse($msg, $email, $name, $price));

        return redirect()->route('registeredCourse.index')
                         ->with('sucess_message', 'Registered course was sucessfully added');

    } catch(Exception $exception) {

        return back()->withInput()
                     ->withErrors(['unexpected_error' => 'Unexpected error occurred while trying to process your request.']);
    }

}
```

My Mailable

```
class RegistCourse extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $subject = 'Registered Course';

    public $msg;
    public $email;
    public $name;
    public $price;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($msg, $email, $name, $price)
    {
        $this->msg = $msg;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->price = $price;

    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('external__emails.registered-course');
    }
}
```

This is my blade template

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div>
                <img src="{{asset('images/logo_leon.png')}}" alt="logo_leon" width="55" id="logo_login"><span style="color:gray">HOLYROOD ENGLISH SCHOOL</span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div>
                <p>Thank you very much for your purchase, {{$name['name']}}. You have just registered in one of our courses.</p>
                <p>
                   
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Course</th>
                            <th>Date of purchase</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>{{$msg['course_id']}}</td>
                        <td>{{$price['price']}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        
                    </table>
                    
                    </p>   
                </p>
                <p>See you in class. Surely we enjoy learning English.</p>
                <p>If you have any questions, do not hesitate to contact us through any of our contact forms.</p>
                <br>
                <p>Equipo Holyrood English School</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Is your price is comma separator ???

Comment: Hi, A.A Noman. I do not undestand well what you want to say. This is my first proyect with Laravel. I think the problem is related with the use of query builder, because returns an array, but I do not what happens. If insteed                             <td>{{$price['price']}}</td> change to <td>{{$price}}</td> it appears on the screen something. I´ve just uploded the image.

Comment: Which data properties are not available?

Comment: Thanks, but it didn´t worked. I ´ve got an exception "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: Added an answer @Noel, regarding `$price`, it should be `$price[0]->price`;

Comment: OMG!!! You are my hero. You were right. I really aprecciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

```
$data = $this->getData($request);
    $email = Auth::user()->email;
    $name = Auth::user(); // Should be Auth::user()->name (if name exists)
    $msg = $data;
    // The get() method returns an array even if there is one row.
    $price = DB::table('courses')->select('price')->where('id', '=', $request['course_id'])->get();
```

So, `$price` should be `$price[0]->price` in the view or use `first()` method instead of `get()`. So, the name should be the property of the `user` model, `Auth::user()` will result in an object.

Answer (score 0):

> pay attention to the '->with' function that I use to send the datas to the view.
>
> **YOUR MAILING CLASS:**

```
class SuccessBooking extends Mailable
    {
        use Queueable, SerializesModels;
    
        /**
         * Create a new message instance.
         *
         * @return void
         */
    
        public $booking;
        public $user;
        public $pdf_path;
        public $rideCode;
    
        public function __construct($user, $booking, $pdf_path, $rideCode)
        {
                $this->booking = $booking;
                $this->user = $user;
                $this->pdf_path = $pdf_path;
                $this->rideCode = $rideCode;
        }
    
        /**
         * Build the message.
         *
         * @return $this
         */
        public function build()
        {
            return $this->from('noreply@coride.com', "Co Ride Receipt")
                ->view('email/successbookinginvoice')
                ->attach(public_path($this->pdf_path))
                ->with([
                'user' => $this->user,
                'code' => $this->rideCode,
                'path' => public_path($this->pdf_path),
                'booking' => $this->booking,
                ]
            );
        }
    }
```

> **YOUR BLADE TEMPLATE**

```
@section('content')
    {{--below we access a particular item in the object user--}}
    <h5>Dear {{$user->firstName}}, congratulations on your successful booking.</h5>
    
    {{--below we just access code, it's not an object--}}
    <h5>Dear {{$code}}, congratulations on your successful booking.</h5> 
@endsection
```